# MySql Backup/Change Monitoring

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL from an admin point of view.

I have spent the last few hours googling with no luck and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction of either what to google for or a suggestion.

Basically I am looking for ideas on how best to monitor the data changes within a MySQL database so that I can at the end of a day look at the activity and either choose to rollback a few transactions or back to the last daily back up.

I think programatically there could be ways to do this with triggers but I am not sure if that is a good route to head down, it is just one that seemed possible to me.

roll back to a previous state.  I think I will be able to do a daily dump of the database that could be rolled back to.

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend triggers. I've used them to provide a replicated copy of a database and it works quite well. From within the trigger, insert a record into another table that indicates the operation performed and any data you need to associate with it.

Comment: Brilliant,  I have added triggers in now.  Seems to work fine.  Planning on clearing the tables periodically to stop too much bloat in the database. Thank you for the quick response.